# RTL8811AU Driver Installation Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, raspberrypi

I am trying to install driver for RTL8811AU chip on my Rasberry Pi 4 with no success to my wifi dongle.
My kernel version is the following

```
uname -r
5.15.0-1048-raspi
```

My wifi dongle is recognized

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
```

I have tried following drivers with no success
https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git
https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git

The last one was installed from source.

My problem is that these two drivers does not work.
Have anyone any suggestion to drivers that works with my kernel?

Comment: Providing details as to what OS/release you're using may have been helpful; the 5.15 kernel you mention for example is used by multiple systems but you've not said which you're using.

Comment: In the duplicate, you should omit the first step, "sudo dkms remove" All following is correct.